# Java libraries in appication server classpath -Linux

Tags: java, linux, websphere

How to check the list of libraries (jar, properties,folders) that is in the classpath of the application which is running in the application server(webpshere 8.1)?

Does ps (process) command in linux gives all the details.
And also , How do we checking the port number(http,admin console,soap) of the application /application server domains?

Aside from WEB-INF/lib ,WEB-INF/classes. which are the folders that application server takes deafault into classpath.

My question is to find out the libraries that are used by server to run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know which jars are loaded into the JVM. In most conditions, 'lsof' can help you:

lsof -a -p < pid > |grep '\.jar'

Comment: Thanks , this helps.Still, need to find the http port number of the application requests

Comment: There is no actual method to know which port the processing using is http or other protocol. To know the port used by the process, please use 'netstat'.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Class viewer service to find out what jar files and libraries reside on the classpath.

For more information:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fttrb_classload_viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the existence of WAS 8.1. However, application classloader in WAS can output all libraries that were loaded. Simply call `toString()` on it from within any class of the application:

```
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to specify java command line parameters for websphere, but for the standard JVM, if you want to see where the class files are loaded from, you can specify the -verbose:class parameter.  Assuming websphere is using a standard JVM at some point, that should help.

Comment: Do we need to include the parameter in the startup script? i.e, may be in java options parameter?